# Oracle delete and insert in one statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table definition and sample data like below.

```
user_id,attr_key,attr_val,rating,status
user_1,k1,v1,5,ACT
user_1,k2,v2,6,ACT
user_2,k1,v1,3,INACT
user_2,k2,v2,2,ACT
user_2,k3,v3,8,ACT
root,k1,v1,9,ACT
root,k2,v2,8,ACT
```

Is it possible to write ONE query statement which can override data of root user with user_2 and if the status of user_2 data is INACT then it should be copied to root with ACT? Please see expected output below.

```
Expected output of query:
user_id,attr_key,attr_val,rating,status
user_1,k1,v1,5,ACT
user_1,k2,v2,6,ACT
user_2,k1,v1,3,INACT
user_2,k2,v2,2,ACT
user_2,k3,v3,8,ACT
root,k1,v1,3,ACT
root,k2,v2,2,ACT
root,k3,v3,8,ACT
```

Hogan's query: (TODO : delete root before INSERT in same statement)

```
INSERT INTO some_table
  SELECT 'root', attr_key, attr_val, rating, 'ACT'
  FROM some_table
  WHERE user_id = 'user_1'
```

Thanks.

Comment: It is possible. But this is not a script writing service; you need to do your own learning and trying. If you are stuck with a specific detail in the syntax, post that question; but don't ask for someone to write the code for you.

Comment: This is just an insert... No data has been deleted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using oracle MERGE statement !

Comment: This was downvoted incorrectly, you can indeed do it with with merge, although it does look hacky.

Answer (score 0):

You want to insert something based on some data with a filter.  Use an insert, select and a where clause:

```
INSERT INTO Your_table_name_which_you_did_not_tell_us
  SELECT 'root', attr_key, attr_val, rating, 'ACT'
  FROM Your_table_name_which_you_did_not_tell_us
  WHERE status = 'INACT'
```

You can't delete and insert in one query.  You perform it as an atomic operation with a transaction like this:

```
WHENEVER SQLERROR ROLLBACK;

BEGIN TRANSACTION;

DELETE FROM some_table WHERE user_id='root';

INSERT INTO some_table
  SELECT 'root', attr_key, attr_val, rating, 'ACT'
  FROM some_table
  WHERE user_id = 'user_1';

COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

This way you will only do the delete if the insert does not fail.  You will also lock the table from modification while the transaction is running.  (there are some commands that can get around that but we hope people know what they are doing if they use them.)

Comment: thanks Hogan. This looks close to what I am looking for. Slightly changing your query in my original question. Only thing left is delete the data before inset. How can I do this in same statement ?

Comment: @user3222372 I don't understand what data you want deleted so I can't help you with that part.

Comment: Alright @user3222372 - I posted an answer -- probably what you want.